Explicit formula for Dold-Kan projection to normalized Moore complex
When proving the classical Dold–Kan correspondence (as e.g. in Goerss-Jardine book or here http://math.uchicago.edu/~amathew/doldkan.pdf), one associates three chain complexes to a simplicial abelian group $A_\bullet$:

The standard Moore complex $A_*$, where the terms are simply $A_n$ and the differentials are $\sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^i d_i$;
The normalized Moore complex $NA_* \subset A_*$, where we only consider those elements of $A_n$ which are annihilated by $d_0$, $d_1$, $\dots$, $d_{n-1}$;
The degenerate complex $DA_* \subset A_*$ consisting of degenerate simplices.

One then proves $A_* = NA_* \oplus DA_* $, and in fact as a part of Dold–Kan correspondence one shows
$$A_n = \bigoplus_{\phi:[n]\to[k] \text{ surjective}} \phi^* NA_k.$$
The question is: are there any explicit formulas for the projections to the direct summands? In particular, can we easily describe the projection $A_n\to NA_n$? This is going to be some combination
$$\sum_{\phi:[n]\to[n]} n_\phi \phi^*$$
of pullbacks through maps $[n]\to [n]$, so it's "just" a bunch (i.e. $\binom{2n+1}{n}$) of numbers.
But even for low $n$'s, this is not very easy and it's hard to see a pattern. For example, for $n=2$, we have the identity and the map $\binom{012}{122}$ with coefficient 1 and the maps $\binom{012}{022}$, $\binom{012}{112}$ with coefficient -1.

I believe that at the end of the day this boils down to inverting a certain upper triangular integer matrix with ones on the diagonal.  Ross Street has a paper along these lines.

Thanks @BenjaminSteinberg! Do you know which paper that is? I can't find anything similar in his list of publications.

Maybe this one https://arxiv.org/abs/1402.7151
